# Expressing equation in terms of a ratio between two variables

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I have

```
x = (-2 h^2 k - 2 h k^2 - k^3 - Sqrt[8 h^4 k^2 + 16 h^3 k^3 + 
     14 h^2 k^4 + 6 h k^5 + k^6])/(2 h^2 + 2 h k + k^2)
```

which has `k` and other symbols as variable and constants, respectively.

How can I express `x` in terms of `k/h` instead?

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
x = ((-2 h^2 k - 2 h k^2 - k^3 - 
       Sqrt[8 h^4 k^2 + 16 h^3 k^3 + 14 h^2 k^4 + 6 h k^5 + 
         k^6])/(2 h^2 + 2 h k + k^2) /. k -> kdh h // Simplify ) 

(*h kdh (-1 - (h^3 kdh (2 + kdh)^2)/Sqrt[h^6 kdh^2 (2 + kdh)^2 (2 + 2 kdh + kdh^2)])*)
```

For `h>0` you get finally

```
x= k (-1 - (kdh (2 + kdh)^2)/Sqrt[kdh^2 (2 + kdh)^2 (2 + 2 kdh +kdh^2)])
```